# Getting Angular routing values dynamically from server

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm working on a project that's an Angular7 project. We want to load routing values from a json which is requested from an app(SAAS server identity-authorization management). I was digging a lot of place but I couldn't find any example. Can I fill routing values from a json file or a service at runtime?

**By the way, if it's not a suitable way for Angular**

*Thank you...*

Comment: Is it the complete Router Config that you want to load?

Comment: you con do it this way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53580756/angular6-synchronously-load-route-data

Comment: @SiddAjmera yeap

Comment: @Mazdak dude you misunderstood me. I don't want to transform json file or data to an object. I want to load routing values from the server

Comment: @MuminKa see the second answer which accepted as the answer, in `app-routing.module.ts` they pass any incoming route request to resolve with `resolve()` method in `resolver.service.ts`. there they get routing values from server and resolve routes based on that data. also they used that data in `content.component.ts` or `navbar.component.ts` to create links based on data. isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, this is not a valid approach on angular side. So I will implement static routing. Thank you for all.